# Как добавить reactions к сообщению на расстоянии друг от друга в python discord?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я использую python discord для написания бота. Для создания "кнопок" я использую reactions:

```
await message.add_reaction("✔")
await message.add_reaction("♥")
await message.add_reaction("☺")
```

И вот что выходит:

[image]

Но мне нужно, чтобы кнопки находились на расстоянии друг от друга. Как мне это сделать? То есть как мне контролировать расстояние между ними

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, библиотека `discogd.py` не предоставляет такой возможности. Как вариант могу предложить использовать эмодзи в качестве разделителей.

Comment: А как это реализовать?

Comment: Просто выберите себе какой-то один эмодзы который и будет разделитель.
Например пусть разделитель будет эмодзы ромба (в дискорди он записывается так ":small_blue_diamond:"), тогда просто после кожно вашего эмодзы вы ставете это `await message.add_reaction (":small_blue_diamond: ')`

Comment: Если добавлять 2 раза один и тот же эмодзи, то он будет выглядеть как один. То есть если нужно разделить 3 реакции, то нужно использовать 2 эмодзи-разделителя. Но так не пойдет. Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Больше нет ибо подругому я не вижу вариантов.

Как я уже говорил в ответе `discord.py` не предоставляет такой возможности.

Ищите какие-то другие способы.

Answer (score 0):

если можно, то добавь невидимую кнопку

Comment: Что за невидимая кнопка? И как ее добавить?